# How to include external library to smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-cpp

I am trying to add libcryptopp library to my contract but when I try to compile with eosio-cpp I get an error that header files cannot be found.

This is my code:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include "cryptopp/integer.h"
#include "cryptopp/sha.h"
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

class[[eosio::contract]] p2pgaming : public eosio::contract
{
public:
  using contract::contract;
  p2pgaming(eosio::name receiver, eosio::name code, eosio::datastream<const char *> ds) : contract(receiver, code, ds){}
   [[eosio::action]] 
   void printsha(std::string message)
  {
    SHA256 hash;
    std::string digest;
    StringSource s(message, true, new HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(digest))));
    eosio::print(digest);
  }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(p2pgaming, (printsha))
```

Comment: What error do you get? What command do you use to copmile eosio-cpp? Where are the libcryptopp lirbary files stored? If you give us useful information we are much more likely to be able to help

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 user has mentioned error read question carefully.

Answer (score -1):

your are getting that error because that header file may be cannot located at given location or you may try this syntax `#include<cryptopp/integer.h>`